# Add data attribute with Jquery to every image

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I need to have a data attribute added to every image on a page. This data images provides a lightbox functionality but since there so many images it would be nice to automate this by using Jquery.

So far I've played with the data attribute possibilities like:

```
$('.item a).attr('data-lightbox');
```

I have multiple images on a pages and all with the .item div should have the data attribute applied to. Am I thinking the right way?

Comment: can you post your html for image with container?

Comment: [`.data( key, value )`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value)

Comment: OP, did my answer help you out?

Comment: JQuery provide more methods like setter and gutter. .attr() method when you provide only key then it gives return value and when you set both key and value then it will change attribute on selection element.

$('.item a').attr('data-lightbox ', 'value');

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job

`$('.item img').attr('data-lightbox', 'value');`

Comment: It's better to use the built in data method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr maybe this justify your point

Comment: Basically this is what did the trick: $j(".item-page a").each(function() {
       $j(this).attr("data-uk-lightbox", "value");
   });

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `getter` method by only passing in the key as a parameter. You need to use a setter and pass in a key and value. The correct syntax is

```
$(selector).data(name,value)
```

Loop over the images and use the `data()` method

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).data("lightbox", "value");
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: This seems like the logic way to do it. It's not working however. I might add that there is NO data attribute present in the div tag. Basically it looks like: <a href="..."></a> and needs to be <a href="..." data-uk-lightbox={'group1'}></a>